# Crop matplotlib imshow to extent of values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to interpolate a surface based on geophysics in the form of x, y, z points. I would like to have the surface cropped to the extent of the of the survey (e.g. I just want the area within the red borders in the below figure).

Doe anyone know how to do this? Below is some example code which generates the below figure. I need to work out how to modify it to just interpolate the area within the red border.

```
# Import libs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Create some example data
x = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8,6,7,8,9])
z = np.linspace(0,100,len(y))

# Grid and interpolate between points
yi, xi = np.mgrid[int(y.min()):int(y.max()),int(x.min()):int(x.max())]
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')

# Plot the figure
plt.imshow(
  zi, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()],
  origin="lower", interpolation='bicubic', aspect='auto'
)
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(x,y, c = 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_clip_path.html) my approach would be:

```
# Import libs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

# Create some example data
x = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8,6,7,8,9])
z = np.linspace(0,100,len(y))

# Grid and interpolate between points
yi, xi = np.mgrid[int(y.min()):int(y.max()),int(x.min()):int(x.max())]
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')

# Plot the figure
im = plt.imshow(
  zi, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()],
  origin="lower", interpolation='bicubic', aspect='auto',
  clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)

plt.colorbar()

path = Path([[1, 1], [1, 4], [6, 9], [6, 6], [1, 1]])
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')

plt.gca().add_patch(patch)
im.set_clip_path(patch)
```

[image]

For calculating the corners of your area you could define a function:

```
def corners(x, y):
    xl = np.min(x)
    yl = np.min(y)
    xh = np.max(x)
    yh = np.max(y)
    return [[xl, yl], [xl, np.max(y[x==xl])], [xh, yh], [xh, np.min(y[x==xh])], [xl, yl]]
```

and replace the explicit points in the patch with that:

```
...
path = Path(corners(x, y))
...
```

EDIT:
with

```
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none')
```

you can purely clip, without necessarily showing the edges of the clippath.

[image]